# Is Organic Groups 7.x ready for production?

Tags: 7, organic-groups

I am about to build a community and planned on using organic groups. I was using drupalmodules.com to download modules, and I noticed that that the reviews for organic groups 7.x are terrible. http://drupalmodules.com/module/organic-groups. Is anyone using organic groups 7.x, and what are your experiences with it?

Comment: The last review was made in April 22, 2012, and a lot has happened with OG since then. OG is complex and if you haven't used it before in D7 it really takes some time to get your head around it. I have used the OG 2 for production and it works pretty okay. Had some issues before but they seem to have been resolved.

Answer (score 1):

I've used OG6 in the past and am starting to use OG7 now for a website.  I'd say in general, both with the 6 and 7 versions that the learning curve in figuring out how to use Organic Groups can be steep for a newbie, since it's a complicated module with a lot of features, and a lot of related, supporting modules like [OG menu](http://drupal.org/project/og_menu), [OG Extras](http://drupal.org/project/og_extras), etc.

Give yourself time to play with all of those.  Don't expect to setup your perfect site in a day if you've never used it before.  It may be that the 6 folks who reviewed the module on the site you referenced had such expectations.  Also, those are **6 reviews out of over 24,000 sites currently using OG**.  :-)

My recommendation: do your own testing and make up your own mind before believing a review 100%.  Some of those reviews are probably quite valid, but OG is a useful module and may be able to do everything you want for your site.